# Make links fit the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

So I am making a website and i've made a navigation bar and put links into it however the links don't fill up the bar how would i make sure the links fill up the whole bar? As in they actually fit the bar i've made and don't let the bar keep going on or stay to the left.

any help would be much appreciated

thank you

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
 .logo{
     width: 100px;
     height: 70px;
     background: pink;
}
 .left{
     width: 100px;
     height: 50px;
     background: transparent;
     float: left;
}
 .right{
     float: right;
     width: 100px;
     height: 50px;
     background: transparent;
}
 .topnav {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: blue;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
}
 .topnav a {
     float: left;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
}
 .topnav a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
     color: black;
}
 .topnav a.active {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="topnav">
               <a href="vvcb">HOME</a>
               <a href="#news">blalala</a>
               <a href="#contact">HELP</a>
               <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
               <a href="#about">LOGIN</a>
               <a href="#about">REGISTER</a>
            </div>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They do fit in higher resolution.. but in lower, nah... What you could do is try Bootstrap and do a collapse when you view your navbar in lower resolution... Check it out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#external-content

Comment: I suggest to you, read structures of list: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp , for SEO it's better to have good structure html code.

Comment: Please don't vandalize question people have taken time to answer

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS Flexbox, this is a great primer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

```
 .topnav {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: blue;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     display:flex;
     justify-content:space-evenly;
     flex-wrap:wrap
}
```

Make the above changes for topnav class. It is using flexbox. You can refer the CSS Tricks guide for flexbox here :  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/7s6hpok9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Give `width: 100%` to your `.topnav` .

```
.topnav {
    width:100%
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: the thing is i want my bar in the middle giving it a width of 100 percent will make it take up the whole page and it doesnt solve the problem of text not being filled up in the bar

Comment: Not necessarily. .topnav will take up 100% of the space given to them using flex-css to flex the address tags will resize those.  flex the .topnav then apply "flex: 1;" ".topnav > * " will then allow you to resize the children

Answer (score 0):

You're using what amounts to a table-based design here. It looks like you want 100px of margin on the left and right, and for the bar to take up the rest of the width, based on your code.

I've removed those extra divs and the corresponding styles, and added CSS that does what you seem to have said you want. There's some optional CSS in there that will resize the text as the viewport gets more narrow, so you can fit more links in there for longer...I'm not sure why you'd want part of the bar to disappear...but here's a start. (Also, you've got some syntax problems in your HTML that I've cleaned up.)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .logo{
            width: 100px;
            height: 70px;
            background: pink;
        }

        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            margin : 0px 100px ; 
            height : 45px ; 
        }

        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            background-color: blue;
            height : 25px ; 

        }

        .topnav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .topnav a.active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

/* 
        @media screen and (max-width : 800px) {
            .topnav a {
                font-size : 1.5vw ; 
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
            .topnav a {
                font-size : 9px ; 
            }
        }
 */

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <div class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="vvcb">HOME</a><a href="#news">blalala</a><a href="#contact">HELP</a><a href="#about">ABOUT</a><a href="#about">LOGIN</a><a href="#about">REGISTER</a> 
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you i can work from this, really appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. It would be helpful to folks if you would "accept" an answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your after.
I only moved the divs `left` and `right` and did not change anything else

```css
 body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   .logo{

    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    background: pink;
   }


   .left{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
   }

   .right{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
   }

   .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
   }

   .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
   }

   .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
   }

   .topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
   }
```

```html
  <div>
    <ul>
        <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="topnav">
     <a href="vvcb">HOME</a>
     <a href="#news">blalala</a>
     <a href="#contact">HELP</a>
     <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
     <a href="#about">LOGIN</a>
     <a href="#about">REGISTER</a>
    </div>
        <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
        </ul>
  </div>
```